# Python Tkinter Button Border Not Following Dimensions

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pycharm

In PyCharm I am trying to make a Tkinter application. I am creating buttons to put in and change their dimensions. When I change the dimensions of each button, I am able to click the button and use it within the dimensions I specified but the border does not outline/follow the dimensions.

I would appreciate the help.

```
button1 = tkinter.Button(root, text="Button1", height=20, width=20, borderwidth=10)
button1.grid(column=0, row=0)


button2 = tkinter.Button(root, text="Button2")
button2.config(height=20, width=20)
button2.grid(column=1, row=0)

button3 = tkinter.Button(root, text="Button3")
button3.config(height=20, width=20)
button3.grid(column=2, row=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The first button shows the shows border, in the next two buttons, you did not mention any border width. I did the following and it looks ok.

```
button2 = Button(root, text = 'Button2', borderwidth = 10)
button2.config(height = 20, width = 20)
button2.grid(column = 1, row = 0)

button3 = Button(root, text = 'Button3', borderwidth = 10)
button3.config(height = 20, width = 20)
button3.grid(column = 2, row = 0)
```